# Debugger connection fails when using UART2 in DMA mode in Nucleo-401RE

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, nucleo

I am trying to build a simple communication between my PC and a Nucleo-F401RE using UART over the USB connection.

I am able to do this successfully using a “polling” or an “interrupt” configuration.

However, when I configure the UART2 of my F401RE as using DMA (I use the CubeMX tool in CubeIDE to do the configuration) and then try to run the program in run or debug mode, I get the error messages:

“Debugger connection lost.
Shutting down...”

Is it not possible to use DMA of UART2??

Many thanks in advance!